# How to get YUV video info?

Tags: ffmpeg, yuv, ffprobe

How can I get information from YUV video file format ? I need to know information about the stream (e.g codec, bitdepth). Using ffplay i can play the yuv video but how to get information about the stream ?

I tried using ffprobe but it did not work. 
e.g, ffprobe -show_streams -i vid.yuv

Answer (score 1):

If it's a raw YUV video file, it does not contain that information. You need to get that separately. The file itself strictly contains video pixel data, nothing else, not even the type or size of video data.

However, if ffplay plays it, it suggests it's not a raw YUV file. Can you post the stdout/stderr of ffplay when playing the video? That may help in giving an appropriate ffprobe invocation also.